# Magento 2 won't list my custom theme

Tags: magento2, theme

I'm starting my first foray into developing a theme for Magento 2 and currently it's not listing my theme when I go to **Stores > General > Design**, only Luma and Blank.

I have set up the theme with the directory structure as outlined [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) and added an entry for the theme in `dev/tools/grunt/configs/registration.php`

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure that your Magento application is in developer mode.**

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

create folder structure and place 2 files in theme root:

```
app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/
```

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'frontend/[vendor]/[theme]',
__DIR__
);
```

theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>[theme]</title>
<parent>Magento/blank</parent>
<media>
    <preview_image>media/preview.png</preview_image>
</media>
</theme>
```

Apply your theme: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html

Delete all files in the pub/static/frontend and var/view_preprocessed directories.

Deploy static resources (SSH to magento root)

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Clear cache and reload.

Comment: In registration.php do I change the THEME in \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME, to my theme name?

Comment: No just replace [vendor] & [theme] with the path to your theme

Comment: I wasn't in developer mode. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

It should be there automatic. Check for typing mistakes.

Clear Caches... switch to developer mode:

```
./bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your magento setup. You need to run the following command to update the database schema.

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```